# How can I configure Storybook.js Webpack with Next.js, Ant Design, Less, and TypeScript

Tags: webpack, less, next.js, antd, storybook

I am trying to configure Storybook to work with Next.js, Ant Design, Less, and TypeScript. I have followed every tutorial I can possibly find and nothing has worked. I will post my configs and the error I'm getting below...

My `.storybook/main.js` looks like:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../**/*.stories.mdx', '../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-ant-design',
  ],
  presets: [path.resolve(__dirname, './next-preset.js')],
};
```

My `.storybook/next-preset.js` looks like:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (baseConfig, options) => {
    // Modify or replace config. Mutating the original reference object can cause unexpected bugs.
    const { module = {} } = baseConfig;

    const newConfig = {
      ...baseConfig,
      module: {
        ...module,
        rules: [...(module.rules || [])],
      },
    };

    // TypeScript with Next.js
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../components'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../stories'),
      ],
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['next/babel'],
            plugins: ['react-docgen'],
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    newConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');

    // // SCSS
    // newConfig.module.rules.push({
    //   test: /\.(s*)css$/,
    //   loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    //   include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../styles/global.scss'),
    // });

    // Less
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/styles'),
    });

    //
    // CSS Modules
    // Many thanks to https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6055#issuecomment-521046352
    //

    // First we prevent webpack from using Storybook CSS rules to process CSS modules
    newConfig.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/'
    ).exclude = /\.module\.css$/;

    // Then we tell webpack what to do with CSS modules
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.module\.css$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../common/components'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../common/layout'),
      ],
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return newConfig;
  },
};
```

And my `.storybook/preview.js` looks like:

```js
require('../assets/styles/antd.less');

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
};
```

My `antd.less` file looks like:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';

@primary-color: red;
```

And finally, my `next.config.js` looks like:

```js
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
  },
  ...withLess({
    lessLoaderOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
    },
  }),
});
```

The error I'm getting when trying to run Storybook is:

```
ERROR in ./assets/styles/antd.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--11-2!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--16-2!./assets/styles/antd.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


import api from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
              ^
Unrecognised input
      in /assets/styles/antd.less (line 1, column 16)
 @ ./assets/styles/antd.less 2:12-284 9:17-24 13:7-14 45:20-27 47:4-60:5 49:6-59:7 50:38-45 56:26-33 58:21-28 68:15-22
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/defaultParameters.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can get Storybook to work if I just leave out all the Less configuration from the Storybook config, but then none of my customization to Ant Design come through.

**Edit 1:**
My relevant dependencies are:

```
"css-loader": "^5.0.1",
"less-loader": "^5.0.0",
"style-loader": "^2.0.0",
"ts-loader": "^8.0.10",
"typescript": "^4.0.5",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.28",
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.28",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.28",
"@storybook/preset-ant-design": "0.0.1",
"@storybook/react": "^6.0.28",
"less": "^3.12.2",
"next": "^9.5.5",
"@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
"@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
""antd": "^4.8.0",
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is a link to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GVanderLugt/storybook-next-antd-less-typescript-config) where you should be able to reproduce the issue by running `npm install` and `npm run storybook`.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I do not. I can try to get one up, though.

Comment: Cool. Let me know as you have done

Comment: @tmhao2005 [here](https://github.com/GVanderLugt/storybook-next-antd-less-typescript-config) is a repo. You should just need to run `npm install` and `npm run storybook` to reproduce the issue. If it was working correctly you should be able to see a primary button story that's red instead of the default blue.

Comment: Is it a question or project?

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani It's a question. I'm trying to figure out how to configure Storybook to work like I've described with Next.js, Ant Design, Less, and TypeScript.

It's really a question about how to configure webpack for Storybook to allow for this. I think I'm close, but I keep getting an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue is from using the original `less` webpack loader configuration. But removing it is not the only thing you make it working.

Here are a few steps you have to do:

- Remove the original less loader before adding yours:

```js
baseConfig.module.rules = baseConfig.module.rules.filter(
  f => f.test.toString() !== '/\\.less$/'
);
```

- Getting `antd` less files complied as well by including them:

```json
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  include: [
    /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*antd/,
    // ...
  ],
}
```

- In short, here is the final your configuration:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (baseConfig, options) => {
    const { module = {} } = baseConfig;
    
    // Remove original less loader
    baseConfig.module.rules = baseConfig.module.rules.filter(
      f => f.test.toString() !== '/\\.less$/'
    );

    const newConfig = {
      ...baseConfig,
      module: {
        ...module,
        rules: [...(module.rules || [])],
      },
    };
    
    // ...

    // Less
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      include: [
        // Include antd to rebuild
        /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*antd/,
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/styles'),
      ],
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    //...

    return newConfig;
  },
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. While your answer did get Storybook building and running it did not actually apply the custom theme to the Storybook components. I figured out that I needed to make your changes as well as remove the Ant Design preset I was already trying to use in `./storybook/main.js`. You can see my final solution in the GitHub repo. I will accept this answer since it solved my root issue.

I am having another issue, however, if you want to check that out too. I'll post another comment with the link to it.

Comment: [Here is the other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772576/how-can-i-configure-storybook-js-webpack-to-work-with-absolute-image-paths-in-cs) I'm having now. Webpack/CSS cannot resolve absolute image paths to images in the `public/` directory.

Comment: I dropped you another suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your help @tmhao2005 and @gdvander - I have found one more gotcha in this setup though. When deploying my project to Heroku the build passes but the app crashes at runtime. The logs report: `Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'` 

I've narrowed it down to Heroku automatically running `npm prune`, which removes a required devDependency. None of this happens when I move all @storybook-related packages to `dependencies`. 

So far I've had no luck fixing this issue other than setting turning off dependency pruning by setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` in Heroku

Comment: I opened an issue with Storybook based on my last comment: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13325