# How can I configure Storybook.js Webpack to work with absolute image paths in CSS modules in a Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, next.js, storybook

I am trying to configure Storybook to work with Next.js, Ant Design, Less, and TypeScript. In Next.js, images have to be stored in the `public/` folder and referenced with absolute paths to be used throughout the project. I am having trouble configuring the Storybook.js webpack to be able to resolve these absolute image paths.

For example, in a CSS module I could have:

```css
.testImage {
  background-image: url('/images/cucumber.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

But Storybook will fail when building with this error:

```
ERROR in ./common/layout/TestImage/TestImage.module.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-1!./common/layout/TestImage/TestImage.module.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '/images/cucumber.png' in '/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/common/layout/TestImage'
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:209:21
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /Users/gerritvanderlugt/Development/misc/storybook-issue/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
 @ ./common/layout/TestImage/TestImage.module.css 2:12-115 9:17-24 13:7-14 45:20-27 47:4-60:5 49:6-59:7 50:38-45 56:26-33 58:21-28 68:15-22
 @ ./common/layout/TestImage/TestImage.tsx
 @ ./common/layout/TestImage/index.tsx
 @ ./common/layout/TestImage/TestImage.stories.tsx
 @ . sync ^\.(?:(?:^|\/|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|\/)\.).)*?)\/)(?!\.)(?=.)[^/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/defaultParameters.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined
```

I tried a few different things with `file-loader`, `url-loader` and `css-loader` but was unable to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GVanderLugt/storybook-next-antd-less-typescript-config) where the issue can be reproduce by running `npm install` and `npm run storybook`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you already have had an image loader configured which means you're able to load image in your app. The issue is `css-loader` doesn't resolve absolute path `/images/cucumber.png` (since it just supports relative path). In order to fix this, you can manually resolve as following:

```js
newConfig.resolve.alias['/images/cucumber.png'] = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/images/cucumber.png');

return newConfig;
```

Comment: Which file does this go into?

Comment: In .storybook/main.js  It's documented in more detail here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config

Comment: Is there a way to do this for multiple files without having to explicitly state their path? I have a couple of urls in various files but they all start with the path `assets/{folder}/{image}` But i need to resolve it to `../public/assets/{folder}/{image}` I've tried and it works when i explicitily state each one but i was hoping there might be a more generic `assets/**/*` catch all that work sort all of them out? - I appreciate this is an old question just thought i'd ask just incase @tmhao2005

Answer (score 1):

Building on @tmhao2005's answer, I created `.storybook/webpack.config.js` with this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  config.resolve.alias['/images/some-image.png'] = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    '../public/images/some-image.png',
  )

  return config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [define a static folder](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook) for Storybook in your run script:  `"start-storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public -p 9001"`

Comment: I am already doing this. The problem is with trying to link to files using `url()` in my CSS files using absolute paths.

Comment: @gdvander Did you ever find a solution for using the url() in your files with absolute paths? i'm having the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

I solved the similar issue with this.

```js
// storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  staticDirs: ['../public']
};
```

[Serving static files via Storybook Configuration](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook-configuration)

Comment: This solution worked for me. 
Make sure to restart your "storybook" script once you make this change for the change to show up.